# Rewrite catalogsearch_result_index from config.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, catalogsearch

I want to rewrite `/catalogsearch/result/index/?q=querystring` to a custom url `/search/querystring`.

For this I have created a custom module and in config.xml added below code :

```
<global>
        <rewrite>
            <custom_module>
                <from><![CDATA[/search\/(.*)/]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[catalogsearch/result/index/$1]]></to>
                <complete>1</complete>
            </custom_module>
        </rewrite>
 ...       
</global>
```

This rewrite code is working and rewrite to `/search/?q=querystring`.
But I want to rewrite to `/search/querystring`. For this I am trying below code :

```
<global>
        <rewrite>
            <custom_module>
                <from><![CDATA[/search\/(.*)/]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[catalogsearch/result/index/?q=$1]]></to>
                <complete>1</complete>
            </custom_module>
        </rewrite>
 ...       
</global>
```

But this code redirect url `/search/querystring` to home page.

How to rewrite `catalogsearch/result/index/?q=` to custom url?

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is solved, below code is working :

```
<global>
        <rewrite>
            <custom_module>
                <from><![CDATA[/search\/(.*)/]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[catalogsearch/result/index/q/$1]]></to>
                <complete>1</complete>
            </custom_module>
        </rewrite>
 ...       
</global>
```